# Conditional expectation and partition theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $X,Y$ be two random variables and consider $E[g(Y)\mid X]$. Suppose $\cup_{i=1}^N A_i= \mathbb{R}$, then do we have some thing like

$$E[g(Y)\mid X]=\sum_i E[g(Y)\mid 1_{Y\in A_i}, X]P[\{Y\in A_i\}\mid X].$$

---

Basically, I am trying to compute the conditional expectation of $g(Y)$ by separating it with different cases based on the value of $Y$.

I get the idea from the following equality, suppose $\cup_i A_i=A$, then
$$P(Y\in A\mid X\in B)=\sum_i P(Y\in A\mid Y\in A_i, X\in B)P(Y\in A_i\mid X\in B).$$

I know the law of total expectation but I don't know whether it can be used here.

Comment: To see why the identity cannot hold in general, one can either go back to the definition of conditional expectation (one wonders if you know it) or look at a simple example. To do the latter, choose $A$ such that $0<P(Y\in A)<1$, define $B=\mathbb R\setminus A$, and choose $g=\mathbf 1_A$. Then the RHS is $$E(\mathbf 1_A(Y)\mid \mathbf 1_A(Y),X)P(Y\in A\mid X)+E(\mathbf 1_A(Y)\mid \mathbf 1_B(Y),X)P(Y\in B\mid X),$$ which is $$\mathbf 1_A(Y)\,(P(Y\in A\mid X)+P(Y\in B\mid X))=\mathbf 1_A(Y),$$ while the LHS is $$P(Y\in A\mid X).$$